# Does mongodb copydatabase function overwrite the destination db?

Tags: mongodb

I use it this way:

```
db.copyDatabase('src','dest', 'server:27017')
```

Does documents in dest are remove or replaced if they have the same id ?

Comment: What does documentation say?

Comment: Not much. It just says that it create the dest if it doesn't already exists, nothing about what it does if it does exists : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not erase the existing database. Rather, it will try to merge the two. Errors will occur when both databases have documents with the same unique keys.

```
> db.copyDatabase('sourcedb', 'destdb', 'localhost:27017')
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: E11000 duplicate key error index: destdb.coll1.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('52ebcb2ab33a160d3f1fb6fe') }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

[Full code of the experiment](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8fDZumv1).

Comment: Can I force to overwrite? Or what is the best practice to get an other db? I even dropped the old database, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [copyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) docs:

> - db.copyDatabase() creates the target database if it does not exist.
> - If the target database exists and no collection from the source       database exists in the target database, db.copyDatabase() copies the
>     collections from the source database to the target database. If any
>     collection from the source database exists in the target database,
>     db.copyDatabase() errors out and does not copy any remaining
>     collections from the source database.